# SQL ORDER BY (CASE), NEWID()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table like the image below. I already have a code that selects all rows that has no RQID and follows by those rows that has RQID.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE moduleexam = 20 
ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN RQID <> '' 
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END, NEWID()
```

[image]

The query works by selecting all rows randomly except those rows that has RQID.

[image]

The problem is in the rows that has RQID. How can I make it that both rows with the same RQID should be sequentially ordered?

P.S. I am using MSSQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN RQID <> '' 
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END, RQID, NEWID()
```

After sorting by empty/not empty it will sort by actual RQID and after that randomly.

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY CASE ... END, RQID, NEWID();
```